# Obtaining visible data from filtered table

Tags: excel, vba

I need to filter out some data from long excel table object. I extracted a single table object from `Worksheets.ListObjects` and filtered it out like that:

```
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Foo"
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="Bar"
```

The table on the Excel's worksheet is now displayed as filtered correctly, but if I try to access it's data, the whole scope is returned. For example this function

```
tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(2, 1)
```

returns the cell from the first row of table instead of the first **visible** row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that the range coming from `SpecialCells()` is (almost always) a discontinuous one, so you have to iterate through its `Areas` and their columns to get the wanted result

```
Function GetAreaRangeItem(areaRng, rowIndex As Long, colIndex As Long)
    Dim iArea As Long, nRows As Long

    With areaRng
        Do
            iArea = iArea + 1
            nRows = nRows + .Areas(iArea).Rows.Count
        Loop While rowIndex > nRows And iArea < .Areas.Count

        If iArea <= .Areas.Count Then
            With .Areas(iArea)
                If colIndex <= .Columns.Count Then
                    GetAreaRangeItem = .Item(colIndex)
                Else
                    MsgBox "column index out of range!"
                End If
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox "row index out of range!"
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

to be used as, for example:

```
MsgBox GetAreaRangeItem(tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), 2, 10)
```

Comment: To be more specific- it's impossible to split the Range object neither by SpecialCells() nor by filtering through Row.Hidden flag. Such operations can only split the Range.Areas subobject and the Areas(1) contains All rows. The next elements of Areas array compose visible Rows, one Row per element.

Comment: @0x6B6F77616C74, which part of my answer should your comment apply to? BTW the assumption that _"Areas(1) contains All rows"_ is incorrect: `.Areas(1)` will collect al the cells belonging to the first chunk of cells the _original_ `Range` object has been divided into by the `SpecialCells()` method called upon it

Answer (score 0):

I've looped through the table and validated on .Row Height, then copied each row to sheet2.

```
j = 1
Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).Resize(tbl.ListRows.Count, tbl.ListColumns.Count).ClearContents
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Foo"
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="Bar"
  For i = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
    If tbl.ListRows(i).Range.RowHeight > 0 Then
         Sheet2.Cells(j, 1).Resize(, tbl.ListColumns.Count) = tbl.ListRows(i).Range.Value
        j = j + 1
    End If
  Next i
```

Comment: This did not resolve the problem. The question is- how to 'grab the value'? Every time I try, I get the value from the whole range, not filtered out by the ".AutoFilter" function

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated the solution to copy each visible row inside the table to sheet2. I know its not the whole range at once, but its a beginning.

Comment: 'ListRows' still contains the whole table